# Nuxt reload api data fails

Tags: api, async-await, axios, nuxt.js

Need some help in solving a reload problem.
I fetch data via service:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const apiClient = axios.create({
 baseURL: 'www.domain/api/v1',
 headers: {
 Accept: 'application/json',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }
})
```

and

```
export default {
 getCompanies() {
return apiClient.get('/companies')
},
```

in store:

```
export const actions = {
 fetchCompanies({ commit }) {
 return CompanyService.getCompanies().then(response => {
  commit('SET_COMPANIES', response.data)
 })
},
```

in pages/companies:

```
async fetch({ store, error }) {
  try {
    await store.dispatch('company/fetchCompanies')
  } catch (e) {
    error({
      statusCode: 503,
      message: 'Unable to fetch Companies at this time'
    })
  }
},
```

works fine, but no data on page reload. 
Some help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using it on a pagination component the reason it is not reloading is that `fetch` it will be called server-side once and in the client-side just when navigating to further routes.

> The fetch method is not called on query string changes by default. If you want to change this behavior, for example when building a pagination component, you can setup parameters that should be listened to through the watchQuery property of your page component. Learn more on the API watchQuery page.

Looks Nuxt documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/

You can use `watchQuery` to fix this.
https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-watchquery

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check that out..I am in doubt now why I should go all the way through the store at all... in some tutorials they call the API's directly in the actual index.vue..can you give me some answer about that.. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I can't find a way to fit in: watchQuery in my code..watchQuery: true or watchQuery (newQuery, oldQuery) {}..no success